# Multiple Class Files C++

Tags: c++, class

I am unsure about the use of separate files for classes. How do I make functions inside the classes? Where do I put it?

QuizMain.cpp:

```
#include "QuizMain.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

QuizMain::QuizMain()
{
    // Hia stackoverflow
}
```

QuizMain.h file:

```
#ifndef QUIZMAIN_H
#define QUIZMAIN_H
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class QuizMain
{
    public:
        QuizMain();
    private:
};

#endif // QUIZMAIN_H
```

Main file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "QuizMain.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    QuizMain qm;

    return 0;
}
```

How would I make a class and call it correctly?

Comment: You just have to declare your member functions in the class declaration (header file) and define them in the cpp file. It's exactly the same as the constructor you put in your example, except you put a return type in front of it both in declaration and definition

Comment: What you have shown is valid and correct code.  Just make sure you compile `QuizMain.cpp` and link the resulting object file into your final executable.

Comment: What do you mean by declare in the header? Say put `void thisfunc()` in the header and `QuizMain::thisfunc(){ <code>}` in the cpp?

Comment: Yeah, it'd work. A function declaration expose the return type, the function name and the function parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example:

QuizMain.cpp file:

```
#include "QuizMain.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

QuizMain::QuizMain()
{
    // Hia stackoverflow
}

void QuizMain::my_new_function(std::string my_name){
    std::cout << "Hi " + my_name +"!" << std::endl;
}
```

QuizMain.h file:

```
#ifndef QUIZMAIN_H
#define QUIZMAIN_H
#include <string>

class QuizMain
{
    public:
        QuizMain();
        void my_new_function(std::string my_name);
    private:
};

#endif // QUIZMAIN_H
```

Main file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "QuizMain.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    QuizMain qm;
    qm.my_new_function("foo");
    return 0;
}
```

Anyway, there is no point from asking such a question here. You should probably find a good book/resource and learn how to write and use functions.

Comment: `using namespace std;` in a header file, seriously?

Comment: Copied and pasted the code, get this error: `unterminated #indef`. What's wrong with it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I did not review the code. I just add what the OP need. feel free to edit what you see suitable

Comment: Find indef and replace it by ifndef

Comment: @Bettorun what if there is a real #ifdef :D

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ you are not. but it is not also my job. This is not a code review website. The OP need something. I did it with the min efforts. Your comment is appreciated since it add a good thing. You can downvote if you find it a bad answer. You can also edit. You can do nothing. That is all the story :)

Comment: @ICantCode same error message? add a #endif at the end of the file with the #ifndef

Answer (score 1):

Normally you have a header file and cpp file. The header file is where you declare your functions and member variables. The cpp file is where you implement your functions.

**quizmain.h**

```
// QuizMain.h file
#ifndef QUIZMAIN_H
#define QUIZMAIN_H
#include <string>

    class QuizMain
    {
        public:
            QuizMain(int quizScore);
            // declare public functions here
        private:
           int quizScore; // declare private member variables here.
    };

    #endif // QUIZMAIN_H
```

**cpp file**

```
// QuizMain.cpp file
#include "QuizMain.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

QuizMain::QuizMain(int quizScore)
{
    this.quizScore = quizScore; // init a quiz score
}
```

**main**

Call and create a class object like this

```
QuizMain quiz(95);
```

Comment: `using namespace std;` in a header file, seriously?

Comment: I just copied and pasted, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to do.
If you use the IDE project, the IDE set you to use the any file. Like code::block IDE But if you do not use the IDE project it is a little different to use.
You should write the `.h` file and then,after all writing you should put `.cpp` file.
Also you can use **interface** class that works by `poiter`.

---

```
/// .h file and declaration 
#ifndef ONE.H
#define ONE.H

 class one {
public:
    one();
    ~one();
 };
#include "one.cpp"
#endif ONE.H
```

then:

```
/// .cpp file and implementation 
one::one(){
    std::cout<<"constructor one"<<std::endl;
}
one::~one(){
    std::cout<<"destructor one"<<std::endl;
}
```

then :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "one.h"
int main()
{
      one o;
}
```

output:

> ```
> constructor one
> destructor one
>
> Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.010 s
> Press ENTER to continue.
> ```